# Как исправить баг в гуглхроме при использовании border-radius?

Tags: html, css

подскажите пожалуйста как исправить баг в хроме.

```css
body{
  background:#1a2b3a;
}
.menu-wrap{
 width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 150px;
}

.menu{
 display: flex;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}

.menu li{
 padding: 30px;
 list-style: none;
 background: #eee;
 border-right: 1px solid #187faf;
 transition: 0.3s;
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
 z-index: 1;
}

.menu li::before{
 position: absolute;
 content: "";
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background: #1292ce;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 display: block;
 z-index: -1;
 /*transition: 0.3s;*/
}

.menu li:hover:before{
 left: -100%;
 z-index: 1;
 transition: 0.5s;
}

.menu li::after{
 position: absolute;
 content: "";
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background: #1292ce;
 right: 0;
 top: 0;
 display: block;
 z-index: -1;
 /*transition: 0.3s;*/
}

.menu li:hover:after{
 right: -100%;
 z-index: 1;
 transition: 0.5s;
}

.menu li:first-child{
 border-radius: 30px 0 0 0;
}

.menu li:last-child{
 border-radius: 0px 30px 0 0;
 border-right: none;
}

.menu li:hover a{
 color: #1292ce;
 font-size: 16px;
}

.menu li a{
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #fff;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-weight: 600;
 transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<body>
 
 <div class="menu-wrap">
   <nav class="top-menu"><ul id="primary-menu" class="menu"><li id="menu-item-15" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home current-menu-item page_item page-item-8 current_page_item menu-item-15"><a href="http://lawyer/">главная страница</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-35" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-35"><a href="http://lawyer/%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%81/">О нас</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-33" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-33"><a href="http://lawyer/%d1%8e%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8/">Юридические новости</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-34" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-34"><a href="http://lawyer/%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b7%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%8b/">Полезные сервисы</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-36" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-36"><a href="http://lawyer/%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%8b/">контакты</a></li>
</ul></nav>                   
  </div>
  </body>
```

При наведение на кнопку "главная страница" несколько раз, в правом и нижнем углу данной кнопки появляется белые точки. во всех остальных браузерах работает нормально. если отключить border-radius то проблемы нет. Подскажите как исправить данную проблему.? может проблема в коде? кто силен в верстке пожалуйста помогите с решением проблемки)

Comment: [скрин](http://prntscr.com/lg78qj) - я так понимаю это они? Странно, но они появляются только если навести на "Главную" а потом перевести курсор на кнопку справа. Если же сверху наводить\убирать курсор, то такого не появляется :-)

Answer (score 0):

протестировал на разных браузерах все одинаково, точек никаких нет!

возможно у вас появляется из-за кроссбраузерности

добавьте к transition

```
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
 transition: all 0.5s ease;
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ. перепроверю на другом компе.